# Strongest bone in body

Tags: human-anatomy, bio-mechanics

AS internet  tells is it is thigh bone which is strongest, but why, it carry only upper part of body, does not heel or any foot bones should be strongest in body as they carry full body weight ?

Comment: No, foot bones don't carry full body weight, the weight is distributed half between two lower limbs, then again half at foot between calcaneus and big toe , small toe heads. So, foot bones may not be carrying as much weight as femur.

Comment: @JM97 as a student of physics I must say all weight on  standing at least must fall on Talus bone of heel, as F=mg works toward center of earth

Comment: Again, I would say neck of femur is stronger since it's not breaking eventhough it's not in line with the direction of weight. Neck of femur is withstanding more force( due to the torque).